# Rails fields_for inside fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How can I achieve something like this?
The structure is => a test has many questions, and a question has many answers.

I have `questions = @test.questions.build` and `questions.answers.build` in the controller.

```
form_for @test do |f|
  f.fields_for :questions do |question_f|
    question_f.fields_for :answers do |answer_f|
      # answer form here
```

It works untill the fields_for :answers.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also put `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your Test and Question model if you want use nested form:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :questions_attributes
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :answers_attributes
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

Try this:

```
form_for ([@test, @question]) do |f|
```

and in your new action in controller:

```
@test = Test.new
@question = Question.new
@test.questions.build
@question.answers.build
```

Comment: It already had the accepts_nested_attributes_for in both Test and Question. The nested form for question works fines, the problem is with the answer *inside* question.

Comment: loop around the @questions and build answers for each question.